# Validating User Input for Filenames

Tags: c

If I was to let a user input a filename for a file (allowing spaces) and validate it to see if it is a bad file name, how would I do so?

The only way right now that I can think of is to create char array like

```
char filename[100]
```

And use a for loop and have nested if statements that checks if each single character of the strings are !@%^*~| and etc by writings lines like these

```
for(...) {
    if(filename[i] == '@'){...}
    if(filename[i] == '!'){...}
}
```

Are there better ways to approach this? Because if I was to doing it like that, I would have A LOT of individual if statements just to test all the possible illegal characters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`strchr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strchr/) for that, and if the return is not null, you have found a bad character.

```
char bad_chars[] = "!@%^*~|";
char invalid_found = FALSE;
int i;
for (i = 0; i < strlen(bad_chars); ++i) {
    if (strchr(filename, bad_chars[i]) != NULL) {
        invalid_found = TRUE;
        break;
    }
}
if (invalid_found) {
    printf("Invalid file name");
}
```

Comment: This is definitely the quickest way, less room for error as well.

Comment: This will disregard the empty string. It is good practice to check for that as well.

Comment: this works fine, but just note that the bad_chars in this example are all valid filenames in Linux, but some invalid like / are missing.

Answer (score 2):

You could try regex:

```
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <regex.h>

int main (void) {
    char fileName[100];
    int comp; 
    regex_t myregex; 

    // Compile the regular expression 
    comp = regcomp(&myregex, "^[a-zA-Z0-9.' '\[\]_-]+$", REG_EXTENDED | REG_NOSUB) ;

    printf("Enter a file name\n");
    scanf("%s",fileName) ; 

    // Compare fileName to the regex 
    if (!regexec(&myregex, fileName, 0 , 0 , 0)) {
        printf("fileName %s is valid.\n", fileName);  
    } else {
        printf("fileName %s is invalid.\n", fileName);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 Nice approach. two comments: 1. it should be noted that this is only for POSIX. 2. `regex_t * myregex; ` should be `regex_t myregex;` and then `regcomp(&myregex,...`

Comment: Thanks, I should have commented and watched my code a little better.

Answer (score 0):

This maybe a unique solution (I don't have enough info on your application, so I will post it anyway), but if you only want alphanumeric names, you can compare the integer value of a range of characters which would be a simple(r) if statement:

If you want to see if its a lower/upper case or a number:

**//pseudo**
if(0-9, a-z, A-Z)continue;

else  reject;

```
for(i=0;...;...){
    if((filename[i]==32)||(filename[i]>47 && filename[i]<58 )||(filename[i]>64 && filename[i]<91)||
    (filename[i]>96 && filename[i]<123))
        continue;
else{
...//reject filename
}
```

Alternatively you can see if its a non-alphanumeric...

```
for(i=0;...;...){
    if((filename[i]<=47) || (filename[i]<=64 && filename[i]>=58) ||
    (filename[i]<=96 && filename[i]<=91) || (filename[i]<=123)){
        reject;
    else{
        ...//nothing
    }
```

http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier (and more appropriate) to write : `...filename[i]>= '0' && filename[i] <= '9' ...` ?

Comment: Not sure, can you give more detail on what you mean by easier?  easier on the eyes? makes more sense? faster? I am not sure what a valid name is so its hard to make a clear suggestion, but rather than trying to compare every non-valid character, I am suggesting that he group them up in as large groups as possible.  I prefer not to use >= as that is usually 2 comparisons rather than one.  It does tend to make it less easy to understand at a glance.

Comment: I have no problem with your approach, I just meant it'll be more readable, and not some magic numbers :)

Comment: you are very much right!  I don't mean to make it unreadable (just coding habits), so I can edit if you think its a good idea?

Comment: Done!  Hope that is better, I added some pseudo code to explain what I am trying to say!  Thanks for the suggestion @BinyaminSharet